# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation in drupal views query

Tags: views, database, blocks, entities

When trying to preview a view containing references to three Field Collection module fields, I get the following error:

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS node_, node.created AS node_created, 'field_collection_item' AS field_data_fi' at line 1`

Here is the full attempted query:

`SELECT field_collection_item_field_data_field_obit_service.item_id AS field_collection_item_field_data_field_obit_service_item_id, node. AS node_, node.created AS node_created, 'field_collection_item' AS field_data_field_service_location_field_collection_item_enti, 'field_collection_item' AS field_data_field_service_time_field_collection_item_entity_t, '' AS field_data_field_service_type__entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_obit_service} field_data_field_obit_service ON node.nid = field_data_field_obit_service.entity_id AND (field_data_field_obit_service.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_obit_service.deleted = '0')
INNER JOIN {field_collection_item} field_collection_item_field_data_field_obit_service ON field_data_field_obit_service.field_obit_service_value = field_collection_item_field_data_field_obit_service.item_id
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0`

I don't know sql that well, but it appears as though some of the references are being truncated due to length. Also there is a reference to an empty string ('') as a column name. Any idea what's wrong and how to correct it?

Comment: I believe the column names are the issue - `node.` and `''`.

Comment: Thanks. It's working after I removed and re-added the fields. Maybe it was just a momentary glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the fields and then adding them back resolved the issue, though I'm not sure how.